# Editing file on remote host using scp not working

Tags: netrw

I'm trying to edit a file on a remote host using `vim scp://user@host//path/to/file`
However, vim just displays "Stopped" and crashes.
Here is the log thats produces when I run `vim -V9 scp://user@host//path/to/file`

https://pastebin.com/0Hk1Zx0Y

Comment: I think V9 might be a bit too much, and it looks like the log got cut off at the end when searching for netrw?

Comment: Tristan, I just edited did a remote edit with `scp://...`. No problem. I tested with Vim 8.1.946 on Ubuntu. The log might be cut off because of the crash.

Comment: As this a crash, you should consider to open a issue at Vims [github project](https://github.com/vim/vim). You'll need to provide other information, like exact version, operating system etc.